# Mandatory and valid parameter in WebAPI request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

can I somehow mark property in my "input object" that goes to action as being mandatory and that it needs to be valid. I.e. if I have:

```
public class MyInput
{
  //[SuperNeeded]
  public int FooBar { get; set; }
  public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to ASP.NET stack throw an exception when request without FooBar or when FooBar isn't number comes. These are valid:

```
FooBar=1&Other=abc
FooBar=3
```

But these are not (don't want FooBar to be 0):

```
FooBar=abc&Other=abc //FooBar is not number
Other=abc //FooBar is missing
```

Any ideas how to easily do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `RequiredAttribute`?

Comment: Yes, but that does not do what I want. The FooBar is then simply 0 (default(int)). I can't then say whether it was FooBar=0 or missing value.

Answer (score 0):

In which case, you'd want:

```
[Required]
public int? FooBar { get; set; }
```

That way you won't simply get 0, you'll get null if it was missing, and 0 if a 0 was passed in.